# Actionscript 3.0: What does the parameter 'e' do in e:KeyboardEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, parameters

Ive been using the 'event' parameter for my KeyboardEvents and MouseEvents in a recent project ive been working on for my course (VERY BASIC).

Im not entirely sure on what the 'e' part of e:KeyboardEvent actually does, and ive been asked to find out what information the parameter 'e' can actually access when using it.

Im sorry if the questions badly written, its been a long night!

**EDIT: If A method takes the parameter (e:KeyboardEvent). what information could we access through the use of the parameter e?**

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have some function like this

```
function someFunction(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    // code
}
```

You can access any information from the [KeyboardEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html) class, just the same as if the parameter were called "event".  The name of the parameter doesn't affect what you can access through it; the type does.

Edit: "e" is just the *name* of the variable - it could be called `fred`, `banana`, or `tyrannosaurusRex`, and it would make no difference.  The thing that determines what sort of information you can access through a variable is its *type* - in this case, `KeyboardEvent`.  If you follow the `KeyboardEvent` link above, you will see documentation for the `KeyboardEvent` class, which will tell you all the things you can do with it.  For example, one of the properties of `KeyboardEvent` is `keyCode`, which tells you which key was pressed:

```
if (e.keyCode == 32)
{
    // 32 is the keyCode for spacebar, so spacebar was pressed
}
```

Comment: Im sorry im finding it hard to understand what this means. Ive altered the question slightly now

Comment: Are you able to at least +1 my answer if you're going to use information from it in your update?

Comment: Heh, coincidence, I swear (I didn't even see your answer until after my edit).  I only added an edit because the OP asked for more info, and well, keyCode really *is* the most important property. +1 anyway in good faith.

Comment: @WesleyPetrowski Was only kiddin' mate :P

Comment: Your edited version helped greatly! Thank you very much, I completely understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

`e` represents an instance of `KeyboardEvent` (the instance being passed to your listening function).

The most important property of `KeyboardEvent` (referenced by `e` in your example) is `keyCode`.

This determines which key is being pressed/released.

eg:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, _keyDown);
function _keyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    trace(e.keyCode); // Will be 65 if you press 'a'.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyboardHandler);

function keyboardHandler(Jack:KeyboardEvent):void{

    trace(Jack.keyCode);///----------see output pannel

}

/////////////////--------or

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyboardHandler2);

function keyboardHandler2(Banana:KeyboardEvent):void{

    trace(Banana.keyCode);////////----see output pannel

}
```

You can type anything inside()including KeyboardEvent

Answer (score 0):

You're naming the event that triggers the function, just like any other var it can be named anything. Then, depending on the type of event, you'll have access to a number of vars and function relating to whatever caused the event to trigger.

Edit: [Here's](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html) what's available to you with a MouseEvent (Public Properties)